# Issue with kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes. I recently installed `kubectl` in my ubuntu machine(A VMware vm) with architecture x86_64.operating system is ubuntu 16.04.Installation steps followed:

```
#curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
#chmod +x ./kubectl
#sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

However when I run kubectl get nodes It shows error:

> The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused-did you
>   specify right host or port?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The error is because you don't have any kubernetes cluster running.

You can install [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/) and use it to setup a single node cluster on your local machine

If you are using AWS as a cloud provider, you can install [kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops) and use it to setup multi node kubernetes cluster in aws.

When you have a cluster running, you can then run the command and get nodes running in the cluster returned

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to connect to a remote Kubernetes cluster? If yes you need a config file containing the connection (and authentication) details. `kubectl` expects this file to be present at `~/.kube/config`. Your cluster admins should be able to provide you that file.

If you are not connecting to a remote Kubernetes cluster, then you must run the cluster on your own machine using [minikube](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube) or any other alternative.